# Never bothered / were never bothered

Tags: exam-questions

> The local authorities **never bothered** to case about the unfortunate happenings.
>
> The local authorities **were never bothered** to case about the unfortunate happenings.

Is the *never bothered/were never bothered* used in above both sentences correct ? If yes, what is the difference in their meaning/usage ?

Comment: What is "to case" intended to mean?

Comment: I assume ***to case*** is a typo for ***to care***, but note that it's not really idiomatic to speak of ***not bothering to care** [about something]*. You either *don't bother about it / don't bother to do it* or you *don't care* about it, but not both at once. Note that *They **were never bothered** to fix the problem* is just about credible, but very uncommon compared to *They **never bothered** to fix it*. It's also a bit ambiguous (did *they* bother, or did *someone else* bother them?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. A more idiomatic alternative to the latter would include *can* / *could*: *They couldn't have been bothered.* I think *...they never bothered to care* is possible, but sounds like an overkill and overemphasis.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **never bothered** means they themselves never bothered.
- **were never bothered** means nobody bothered them.

Both usages are correct but, as you can see, have difference in meaning.

Comment: *To case about* is not correct in this context. You might use *to inquire about* or *to investigate*. I have seen instances of *to case the joint* meaning to search/investigate/examine the premises or *to case something up* meaning to enclose it in a case but both are examples of slang or, at least, informal English.